# How to resolve a Graphql Union with Gorm?

Tags: go, graphql, go-gorm, gqlgen

I have a union on two concrete types **Prodotto** and **ProdottoVariante** both implements a interface of type **Articolo**.

```
union Articoli = Prodotto | ProdottoVariante

extend type Query {
  articoli: [Articoli!]!
}
```

I want to query all Prodotto and all ProdottoVariante by typing **articoli** but I don't know how to resolve **Articoli**

I'm trying in this way:

```
func (r *queryResolver) Articoli(ctx context.Context) ([]model.Articoli, error) {
    var articoli []model.Articoli

    r.DB.Model(&model.Prodotto{}).Select("nome").Find(&articoli)
    r.DB.Model(&model.ProdottoVariante{}).Select("nome").Find(&articoli)

    return articoli, nil
}
```

and I'm querying in this way:

```
query {
  articoli {
    __typename
    ...on Prodotto {
      nome
    }
  }
}
```

but I get this error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "must not be null",
      "path": [
        "articoli",
        0
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

```
sql: Scan error on column index 0, name "nome": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type string into type *model.Articoli
```

How to correctly resolve Unions with gorm?

Answer (score 1):

You could always try to create a join between `prodotto` and `prodotto_variante` tables and select the needed columns to populate the fields in the `Articoli` struct.

I'm not sure how your `prodotto` and `prodotto_variante` tables relate to each other. I'm also assuming that the `nome` column is part of the `prodotto` table and that it corresponds to a field in the `Articoli` struct. The code would look something like this:

```
func (r *queryResolver) Articoli(ctx context.Context) ([]model.Articoli, error) {
    var articoli []model.Articoli

    err:= r.DB.Table("prodottos").
               Join("JOIN prodotto_variantes pv ON prodotto.id = pv.prodotto_id").
               Find(&articoli).Error

    return articoli, err
}
```

The above code should populate the entire `Articoli` struct, if the struct fields match the columns in the `prodottos` table.

If you want to populate just some of the fields, you can do it in a couple of ways.

**Example 1**

```
// this should work if populating more than one field
err:= r.DB.Table("prodottos").
                   Join("JOIN prodotto_variantes pv ON prodotto.id = pv.prodotto_id").
                   Select("prodottos.id, prodottos.nome").
                   Find(&articoli).Error
```

**Example 2**

```
// this should work if you want to populate only one field
type Art struct {
   Nome string
}
var arts []Art
err:= r.DB.Table("prodottos").
                   Join("JOIN prodotto_variantes pv ON prodotto.id = pv.prodotto_id").
                   Find(&arts).Error
```

Comment: it says: "ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table \"prodotto\" (SQLSTATE 42P01)",

Comment: ok I added "s" at the end of tables names and now it says: ""sql: Scan error on column index 0, name \"nome\": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type string into type *models.Articoli",

Comment: Is `nome` part of the `Articoli` struct? Could you please add the definition of the `Articoli` struct to your question?

Comment: If anything else is needed, could you please provide more information about the `Articoli` struct and the database schema you are using?

Comment: nome is part of Articoli struct

Comment: I've updated the answer and added more examples.